# Python: Copy files with wildcard in filename

Tags: python, copy, wildcard, shutil

I just started learning Python and I am trying to copy a set of PDFs from one folder to another based on a list of values that match the first four numbers of the PDF filename. (E.g., my value: 1015; file name: 1015_Agyemang_EJPH). I've tried to copy the files using the below code, but Python doesn't seem to recognize the wildcards - and none of the files move

```
import os, shutil
src="U:\User\Source"
src_files = os.listdir("U:\User\Source")
dest = "U:\User\Dest"
files = ['1010*', '1011*', '1015*'] #More values
for file_name in files:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, dest)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd want to use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

```py
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('dir')
['dir']
>>> glob.glob('dir/*')
['dir/c', 'dir/b', 'dir/a']
```